# Liquid - Convert Array to Lowercase

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm using Shopify and want to hook into customer tags, however they are case sensitive.  So `{% if customer.tags contains "wholesale" %}` is not the same as `{% if customer.tags contains "Wholesale" %}`.  My client may or may not stick to one case when applying tags so I want to guard against that in the future.

I would like to take an array, customer.tags, and convert all of the values to lowercase.  I'm trying to work out the logic but am having trouble.

I want to put customer.tags into a new array which isn't working.

```
{% assign newArray = customer.tags %}
{{ newArray }}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [the `downcase` filter](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/filters/string-filters#downcase) for this:

```
{% assign contains_wholesale = false %} 

{% for tag in customer.tags %}
  {% assign lowercase_tag = tag | downcase %}
    {% if lowercase_tag == 'wholesale' %}
      {% assign contains_wholesale = true %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Note: `downcase` just works for ASCII characters. If you need to search for strings with accented letters or other Unicode characters then this won't be enough.

Answer (score 5):

if you would like to keep `customer.tags` as an array so you can keep using `contains` in a simple `if` statement (like your example). You could also chain a couple of liquid filters together to turn all of the strings within the array to lowercase.

Example:

```
  {% assign lowercaseTags = customer.tags | join: ',' | downcase | split: ',' %}
  {% assign randomString = 'WholeSale' | downcase %}

  {% if lowerCaseTags contains randomString %}
    {% comment %}
    Will now match regardless of case sensitivity
    {% endcomment %}
  {% endif %
```

Explanation:

- [Join filter](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/join/): Turn the array into a string seperated by ,
- [Downcase filter](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/downcase/): make the whole string lowercase
- [Split filter](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/split/): opposite of join, recreates the array from the string based on the character used in join `,`

Answer (score 3):

Another solution as you use the "contains" operator would be to skip the "w".

Something like {% if customer.tags contains 'holesale' %} should work.